# iOS 6 UISearchBar cancel button in landscape did not displayed, but displayed in portrait on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UISearchDisplayController` above a UITableView. My code works on iPhone iOS 6/7 and iPad iOS 7.

But on iPad with iOS 6, I have this result in landscape
[image: Landscape]

and in portrait
[image: Portrait]

Where is the cancel button?

I use

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self.searchController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}
```

to be sure that the controller is activated.

Have you an idea?

Comment: You can place a custom cancel button over the search bar cancel button.

Comment: It's a solution to make a work around but I always don't know why I have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
UIView *searchBarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[searchBar bounds]];
[searchBarView addSubview:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBarView;
```

Comment: I use `[[UISearchDisplayController alloc]initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];` to init the UISearchDisplayController so I don't want to use the `navigationItem.titleView`